# The correct token to use with GraphQl?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, graphql

I'm using the latest official aws [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/amplify_auth_plugin_interface) and the flutter graphql [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter). I want to use AppSync. And in the graphql readme it describes how to do this.

> To use with an AppSync GraphQL API that is authorized with AWS Cognito
> User Pools, simply pass the JWT token for your Cognito user session in
> to the AuthLink:

```
// Where `session` is a CognitorUserSession
// from amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2
final token = session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
  getToken: () => token,
);
```

My problem is from the aws plugin, There is a method called `fetchAuthSession` that returns a [session](https://pub.dev/documentation/amplify_auth_cognito/latest/amplify_auth_cognito/CognitoAuthSession-class.html) with different tokens. But it doesn't return the jwtToken.. Are any of the returned tokens used for AppSync? Please click the session link for the different tokens...

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? I am also trying to figure out how to call AppSync!!

Comment: the token is called `accessToken` see below how to get it @AshootoshBhardwaj

Comment: thanks.. I was using native cognito Authentication page using Webview inside Flutter. The Access Token and ID Token were both part of authenticated URL. I used substring thereafter to parse Access Token and that did the trick.. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

The token that you need for AppSync can be got by the Amplify plugin. It's called `accessToken`

```
Future<String> getAcessToken() async {
    CognitoAuthSession res = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true));
    final accessToken = res.userPoolTokens.accessToken;
    return accessToken;
  }
```